# MongoDB Grouping and Project Custom Fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I am stuck with MongoDB grouping and project custom fields. I have the following collection:

```
{ 
    "DescId" : "1", 
    "Desc" : "Testing", 
    "ParentId" : "null", 
    "Order" : 1.0, 
    "Type" : "A", 
    "Parent" : null
}

{ 
    "DescId" : "1.1", 
    "Desc" : "Testing Child 1", 
    "ParentId" : "1", 
    "Order" : 1.0, 
    "Type" : "B", 
    "Parent" : "Testing"
}

{ 
    "DescId" : "1.2", 
    "Desc" : "Testing Child 2", 
    "ParentId" : "1", 
    "Order" : 2.0, 
    "Type" : "B", 
    "Parent" : "Testing"
}
```

I have done following grouping based on Type, DescId, Desc fields and projected DescId and Desc

```
db.getCollection("GenericData").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : {
                "Type" : "$Type", 
                "DescId" : "$DescId", 
                "DescName" : "$Desc"
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : 0.0, 
            "Id" : "$_id.DescId", 
            "Name" : "$_id.DescName", 
            "Type" : "$_id.Type"
        }
    }
], 
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : false
}
```

);

This is the output I am getting:

```
{ 
    "Id" : "1.2", 
    "Name" : "Testing Child 2", 
    "Type" : "B"
}
{ 
    "Id" : "1.1", 
    "Name" : "Testing Child 1", 
    "Type" : "B"
}
{ 
    "Id" : "1", 
    "Name" : "Testing", 
    "Type" : "A"
}
```

Would it be possible to project fields based on Type field, like concatenating Type value with field name like following:

```
{
    "A" + "Id" : "1",
    "A" + "Name" : "Testing"
},
{
   "B" + "Id" : "1.1",
   "B" + "Name" : "Testing Child 1"
}
{
   "B" + "Id" : "1.2",
   "B" + "Name" : "Testing Child 2"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename your object's keys you have to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) operators. First one can convert your `$$ROOT` object into an array of keys and values. Then you can apply [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to modify keys (using [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/index.html)) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to exclude `Type` key. Then you can convert that array back to an object using `$arrayToObject` and promote that object to a root level using [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html). So you can add below stage to your aggregation pipeline:

```
db.GenericData.aggregate([
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: { 
                            $filter: { 
                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, 
                                as: "kv", 
                                cond: { $in: [ "$$kv.k", [ "Id", "Name" ] ] } 
                            }
                        },
                        as: "kv",
                        in: {
                            k: { $concat: [ "$Type", "$$kv.k" ] },
                            v: "$$kv.v"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

outputs:

```
{ "BId" : "1.2", "BName" : "Testing Child 2" }
{ "BId" : "1.1", "BName" : "Testing Child 1" }
{ "AId" : "1", "AName" : "Testing" }
```

EDIT: 
If you'd like to explicitly specify which properties should be projected you can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator inside `$filter`

Comment: Thanks @mickl, this works, although will it be possible to select few fields, instead of all of them?

Comment: @VaniKulkarni yes, modified my answer

Comment: Great! You are my saviour. Thank you so much for this help!

Comment: I had one more query. Will it be possible to display the parent and its future generations in a single document? Something like this: `{ "AId" : "1", "AName" : "Testing", "BId": "1.1", "BName" : "Testing Child 1"}`

Comment: @VaniKulkarni please describe that in a separate question